# Review for ruby "if" statement

Tags: ruby, string, if-statement

do you have any suggestions for making this `if` condition shorter (more elegant) somehow?

```
if (@path.start_with? "scp" || @path.start_with? "http")
  @source = "url"
else
  @source = "local"
end
```

What if I have few more prefix to check (let's  say ftp1, ftp2, and ftp3)?

Comment: what do you want the result of these new prefix's to be?

Comment: For code reviews there is another site:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Meier thank you, I have never seen this site before! Awesome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`start_with?` can take multiple strings as argument

```
@source = @path.start_with?("scp", "http") ? "url" : "local"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might makes sense to extract the prefixes into an array first when the list gets longer:

```
URL_PREFIXES = %w[ scp http ]
```

I can think of serveral ways to use that `URL_PREFIXES` constant. For example I often prefer `if...else` blocks over one liner of readability reasons:

```
if URL_PREFIXES.any? { |p| @path.start_with?(p) }
  @source = 'url'
else
  @source = 'local'
end
```

Or this:

```
@source = 'local'
@source = 'url' if URL_PREFIXES.any? { |p| @path.start_with?(p) }
```

Or determine the prefix first:

```
prefix  = @path.split(':').first
@source = URL_PREFIXES.include?(prefix) ? 'url' : 'local'
```

If you are working with Rails you might want to write this instead:

```
prefix  = @path.split(':').first
@source = prefix.in?(URL_PREFIXES) ? 'url' : 'local'
```